# How do BN layers work in DCGAN while using keras?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, batch-normalization, dcgan

I train a DCGAN on CelebA dataset using keras whose version is 2.2.4.I'm confused about the keras functional API implementation like **predict** about BN layers in the DCGAN architecture.

During training,I need to use **generator.predict(noise)** to get some fake images for discriminator training.And I need to draw samples during training to show whether the network is improving using **generator.predict(noise)** too.I'm aware that during discriminator training the fake images generated by the generator should pass through the BN layers in the generator in **training mode**,and when drawing samples from the generator the way should be done in **test mode**.Because I'm using **predict** method in both situations,I wonder how can I make sure the training and test mode are using correctly in that method.And anyone can tell me if I finished the training, which mode the BN layers are in when I use **predict** method.Thanks.

The code is as this in one iteration:

```py
noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(batch_size, noise_dims))
fake_batch = generator.predict(noise) # are the BN layers in training mode?
real_batch = data_loader.load_data(batch_size)
# train discriminator
discriminator.train_on_batch(real_batch, np.ones(batch_size)*0.9)
discriminator.train_on_batch(fake_batch, np.zeros(batch_size))
# train generator
discriminator.trainable = False
noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(batch_size, noise_dims))
combine_model.train_on_batch(noise, np.ones(batch_size)) 
# combine_model is built by Model(noise, discriminator(generator(noise)))
# I also wonder whether this generator and discriminator call are in training mode

if iter % sample_interval == 0:
    noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(sample_size, noise_dims))
    generator.predict(noise)
    # are the BN layers run in test mode?
```

Want to know if my understanding about BN layers in DCGAN is right and how **predict** method in keras handle the training or test mode in BN or dropout.Finally if possible how to manually control the mode in DCGAN training while using keras(set_learning_phase?).